# Output single row with latest record without null values Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table which looks like below.

| id | job_id | object | message | last_Exception | second_last_Exception |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 312 | 1 | abc | deadlock | 26-04-2021 | null |
| 312 | 0 | abc | connection reset | null | 25-04-2021 |
| 313 | 0 | cde | connection reset | 25-04-2021 | null |
| 313 | 1 | cde | deadlock | null | 24-04-2021 |

Basically i have to print the latest record for each object and if the second_last_Exception_time is null then it should fetch it from the next record. It is also given that for a single object there will be only two rows.

Ideally the output should be like this.

| id | job_id | object | message | last_Exception | second_last_Exception |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 312 | 1 | abc | deadlock | 26-04-2021 | 25-04-2021 |
| 313 | 0 | cde | connection reset | 25-04-2021 | 24-04-2021 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only idea I have is to self join your table

```
select t1.id, t1.job_id, t1.object, t1.message, t1.last_exception, t2.second_last_exception
  from some_table t1
  join some_table t2
    on t1.id = t2.id and t1.object = t2.object
 where t1.last_exception is not null
   and t2.second_last_exception is not null
```

UPD. if second_last_exception is ALWAYS less than last_exception (which it seems logical to me), you may use lead function and filter lines you don't need later in the outer query

```
select * 
  from (select id, job_id, message, last_exception, 
        lead(second_last_exception) over(partition by id, object order by nvl(last_exception, second_last_exception) desc) sec_last_exc
          from some_table)
 where last_exception is not null
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this but even i am approaching on the same way but thinking to optimize it even further or probably if any functions can be used to avoid the self join. Just forgot to mention i am using 12c version.

Comment: @AkashBurnwal you can do it easier if you have an ordering criteria. Then you may use "lead" functions

Comment: @AkashBurnwal check my updated answer please. This one you might be better

Comment: Updated one works fine as well and it is more neat and clean. Thanks :)